# How can I associate a particular userID with a particular table view cell?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am creating an app that has a table view of users that I am pulling down using JSON. The table view is populating with all the information I want, however I am just doing basic information. What I want to happen is a user will click on a table view cell and it will take them to another view controller and in that view controller there will be a more detailed profile view. In my JSON I am getting all of the user information when the table view initially loads like UserID and such, and I want to associate that user ID with each individual table cell so that when they are clicked I can run a php script in the next window to display the profile of the user from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is to first map the JSON to model objects and use those model objects in the table data source to populate the table view. When a cell is tapped, I do the reverse mapping (from cell to model object) and can forward the model object (or a subset of the model object's information) to the next view controller in `prepare(for:sender:)`. To make this happen, I set up the cell in Interface Builder to trigger a segue to the details view controller on selection.

Example code:

```
struct User
{
    let id: String
    let name: String
    // etc.
}

class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var users: [User] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let json = getJSON()
        users = createUsers(from: json)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Check segue.identifier, left out for brevity.
        let destination = segue.destination as! YourDetailsViewController
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        destination.user = user
    }

    // ... other funcs for table view ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        // dequeue cell, set up with info from user, return it
    }
}
```